# load content via hashchange + jquery based on file name not in hash

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, hashchange

I am using jquery + the hashchange plugin from ben alman.  Below is a standard way to grab the hash name and load in content

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
var hash = location.hash;
var array_url = hash.split('#');
var page = $(array_url).last()[0];
$('#content').load( page + '.php', function(){
});
});
```

But is there any way to do this by grabbing some other variable assigned on a click function or sorted through php, perhaps?

I am working with a multi-artist portfolio site that hands out unique three-four letter codes to images

I'd like to serve these images up through unique urls. This has to be through ajax for many reasons.

I had difficulty adding other ajax history options because this page is already using ajax pagination (to load this content) and lots of htaccess url modrewrites.

I am thinking this might just be impossible.

Here is my current code

```
$('a.photo').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href'),
    image = new Image();
    image.src = url;
    var clickedLink = $(this).attr('id');
    location.hash = clickedLink;
    image.onload = function () {
         $('#content').empty().append(image);
    };
    image.onerror = function () {
       $('#content').empty().html('That image is not available.');
    }
    $('#content').empty().html('Loading...');
    return false;
});

$(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    var url = ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' );
    document.title = url;
})

$(window).hashchange();
```

and my html / php :

```
$thethumb = customuniqueidfunc();

<a href="[IMG URL]" 
class="photo gotdesc nohover" rel="<?php echo $row['description'] ?>" 
id="<?php echo $thethumb; ?>">
```

This works insofar as the image from the `href` attr loads into the `#content` div and the hash from the `id` attr is added as a hash to the url and to the title of the page, but I am lacking any mechanism to combine the click and the hashchange function, so that each hash actually corresponds to the image.

Comment: I'm confused as to what specifically you are asking for, or trying to do. Can you clarify your goal at all?

Comment: sorry- i am trying to load content with ajax that is bookmarkable, with back buttons, using hashchange, but hooking hashchange up to get another variable, one that is not the hash ... i hope that helps but i am afraid it doesn't

Comment: So what specifically do you need help with then? Do you need help making it bookmarkable/ history friendly?   Also, do you need help "hooking hashchange up to get another variable"? If so, what variable, and what do you mean by "get "? I want to help you I just need to have these things clarified, thank you for explaining.

Comment: @JonathonG hey, hopdfully you're still in a helpful mood :) what i need help with is triggering hashchange to load content into a div based not on the hash, but on another variable like you said - the unique id being generated in php that is stored in the id attr of the the link.  end use - a user clicks on image (with href attr = img and id attr = id), the href img loads in div and id attr loads in hash.  you can see an example of code above at http://whitecu.be/user/mountain thanks!

Comment: Yes, still in the mood. I will work on it and get back to you soon.

Comment: It looks like what you are asking is already working? Do you just need help making it work with the "forward" and "back" buttons as well as being bookmarkable?

Comment: So that clicking on http://whitecu.be/user/mountain#cGn would take you to the image associated with cGn instead of the /user/mountain page?

Comment: @JonathonG yea, the problem is with it being bookmarkable. i think the call needs to come from hashchange rather than click, from what i've read, just not sure how to do that. for example, if the user were to go to whitecu.be/user/mountain/#cGn, i'd want it to pull up the cGn image into the div box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method I've used for this before is to run a hash polling function. You can see it in action at this page:

http://www.webskethio.com/#services

Here is the javascript for that page:

http://www.webskethio.com/ws.js

Relevant code:

```
function pollHash() {

    //exit function if hash hasn't changed since last check
    if (window.location.hash==recentHash) {
        return; 
    }
    //hash has changed, update recentHash for future checks 
    recentHash = window.location.hash;

    //run AJAX to update page using page identfier from hash 
    initializeFromUrl(recentHash.substr(1));

}

$(document).ready(function(){

    /* code removed for readability */ 

    setInterval('pollHash()',100); // Important piece

    /* code removed for readability */


});
```

and

```
//AJAX function to update page if hash changes
function initializeFromUrl(fromLink) {

    /* code removed for readability */


    //take hash from function call or from the URL if not
    input = fromLink || window.location.hash ;

    //remove # from hash
    output = input.replace("#","");



    //get the URL of the AJAX content for new page
    pageId = output;






var url = $(this).attr('href'),
image = new Image();
image.src = url;
var clickedLink = $(this).attr('id');
location.hash = clickedLink;
image.onload = function () {
     $('#content').empty().append(image);
};
image.onerror = function () {
   $('#content').empty().html('That image is not available.');
}
$('#content').empty().html('Loading...');       




}
```

[**EDIT :**] Here is the full code for your page that should work, provided you can create a page that just outputs the image's location from the database.

```
var recentHash = "";
var image_url ="";

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.photo').click(function (event) {
        var clickedLink = $(this).attr('id');
        location.hash = clickedLink;

        event.preventDefault();
    });


    setInterval('pollHash()',100);

});

function pollHash() {

    //exit function if hash hasn't changed since last check
    if (window.location.hash==recentHash) {
        return; 
    }
    //hash has changed, update recentHash for future checks 
    recentHash = window.location.hash;

    //run AJAX to update page using page identfier from hash 
    initializeFromUrl(recentHash.substr(1));

}


//AJAX function to update page if hash changes
function initializeFromUrl(fromLink) {

    /* code removed for readability */


    //take hash from function call or from the URL if not
    input = fromLink || window.location.hash ;

    //remove # from hash
    output = input.replace("#","");



    //get the URL of the AJAX content for new page
    pageId = output;
    if(pageId != ""){
        var temp_url = 'http://whitecu.be/user/mountain/'+pageId+'.html';
        $.get(temp_url, function(data) {

            image_url = data;
            image = new Image();
            image.src = image_url;

            image.onload = function () {
                $('#content').empty().append(image);
            };
            image.onerror = function () {
                $('#content').empty().html('That image is not available.');
            }
            $('#content').empty().html('Loading...');       

        });



    }else{

        window.location = "http://whitecu.be/user/mountain";

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks so much for the help! i'm still a little confused though.  i undertand the pollhash function and that its being run ever 100 milliseconds to look for a new hash. but what is this `pageId = output;`, what is `output`

Comment: I just posted code directly from my scripts, with a bunch of things removed. You can replace $("hiddenContent).fadeout.... and onward with your current code to load the image into the div. I've gone ahead and done that for you in my answer, but it will likely need some tweaking on your part, I hope this helps you see how to use this though.

Comment: @user1061301 if you do it this way, you can actually remove that stuff from the .click() and just make that change the hash, the polling function will take care of the rest when it sees the hash changed. (this happens so fast the user doesnt notice a delay)

Comment: thanks again for the help! unfortunately, i haven't quite figured it out. i've added this click function, but when i change the hash or even manually type it in, nothing happens.  i've put an alert in the intializeFromUrl function, but it never triggers, which makes me think that its not getting called ...  `$('a.photo').click(function (event) { var clickedLink = $(this).attr('id'); location.hash = clickedLink; event.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: can you chat with me in a stackoverflow chat room?  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4823/chit-chat

Comment: i have to have 20 rep to chat i guess, want to do im or gmail?

Comment: This answer actually gave me another way of doing what I was trying to do. +1. awesome